# Vectorize rolling mean?

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization, rolling-computation

I already know about convolution and I have done it. However I have heard that it can be even faster.

Data-example:

```
0    2
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    4
8    2
9    3
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.8
8    2.2
9    2.4
```

The solutions I already now:

```
df["x"].rolling(5).mean()
```

Than the solution with convolution:

```
c = np.convolve(df["x"], np.ones(5), mode="valid")
c / (np.ones(len(c))*5)
```

Let's say you have a window of size 5, than the change in the rolling is always x_n - x_n-5 / 5, that is x_n is the current and x_n-5 is the one that gets kicked out of the rolling average.

The first 5 would still need to be computed the old fashion way and than the average of the first 5 elements would be added to the cumulative soon.

I am not sure it is faster, I would like to implement it anyway.

Comment: Please update a sample with data and your usual way to implement the rolling mean. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Corralien Ok, I added now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be more optimized, you can just rewrite your convolution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(1, 10, int(1e9))})


# from scipy.signal import convolve
>>> %timeit convolve(df["x"], [1]*5, mode="valid") / 5
5.76 s ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


>>> %timeit np.convolve(df["x"], [1]*5, mode="valid") / 5
8.63 s ± 112 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


# from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
>>> %timeit sliding_window_view(df['x'], 5).mean(axis=1)
20.9 s ± 118 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


>>> %timeit df["x"].rolling(5).mean()
Killed...
```

It depends on the size of your array but I don't know how to go faster.

Comment: THanks. To be honest, I want to implement the idea with the change in moving average being the between new element and last divided by 5.

Comment: Something like `(df['x'] + df['x'].shift(5)) / 5`?

Comment: Yes, this + add the average of opening 5 and cumsum gives a rolling average. Will test if it is faster.